# Install and Run .apk on Android Emulator from Command Line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

I have to install and run an application from command line on android emulator.I have read android developer documentation for the same, and implemented as follows.

To install apk on emulator : `adb -d emulator-5554 install path/to/my/app.apk`

this successfully installed the apk on the running virtual machine.I cant open the installed application, for that I have tried both the installation and running together by the command

`adb -d install path/to/your/app.apk` ,

but this command shows an error "

> error: device not found
>
> -waiting for device-

I have tried the command after starting the emulator but it still diplays the sane error

Answer (score 4):

`-d` for device

you need to use

```
-e for emulator
```

to install apk into your emulator you need to use

```
adb -e install c:\myapk.apk
```

adb options

```
 -a                            - directs adb to listen on all interfaces for a connection
 -d                            - directs command to the only connected USB device
                                 returns an error if more than one USB device is present.
 -e                            - directs command to the only running emulator.                                 returns an error if more than one emulator is running.
 -s <specific device>          - directs command to the device or emulator withthe given
```

Comment: that works fine, but it only installs the application not runs, do you know how to run ?

Comment: it will only install. you need to do manually launch the app.

Comment: yes you can do it thru adb shell am start -n com.yourpack.name/com.package.name.LaunchActivity

Comment: but i don't know the package name.

Comment: ok launch the app manually open the hierarchyviewer and check the name .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50753/discussion-between-shajeer-ahmd-and-padma-kumar)

Answer (score 2):

After installing the application you can start using the command --- 
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n package_name/.main_activity_name

ex:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.flash/.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

1. First Check How many devices are attached to your system. That can be emulator(Virtual Device). or it can be Physical Device `ie Mobile Devices attached externally.
   To know list of devices run command from command-line.
   Locate your Adt-bundle -> sdk->Platform Tools->adb
   I have adb at this path ==> D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools

Commands To Be Followed:

```
adb devices  // It will list devices with their Unique id
adb -s "DeviceIdFromListOfDevices" install path+apkName
```

You are done with installation.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL and RUN:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb install -r path/to/my/app.apk
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.mypack.name/.MainActivity
```

The first command line installs your app. Param `-r` delete a preinstalled version. `path/to/my/app.apk` is to be replaced with your real path and apk name. The second command starts your app. `com.mypack.name/.MainActivity` is to be replaced with your package name.

If you want get the emulator into the front of all windows you can attach the additionally the following lines. There will be created a Windows script file. The script will be executed and after that the file will be deleted.

```
echo new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate("emulator"); > tmp.js
cscript //nologo tmp.js & del tmp.js
```